# Add number of occurence of a string in a data frame

Tags: r

because I do not know how to describe my problem in a proper way in text I present you an example. I' ve the following data frame:

```
my.data = data.frame("names" = c("Michael","Thomas","Daniel","Peter","Michael","Thomas","Ruben","Thomas"))
```

which gives:

```
    names
1 Michael
2  Thomas
3  Daniel
4   Peter
5 Michael
6  Thomas
7   Ruben
8  Thomas
```

and my desired output is:

```
      names
1   Michael
2    Thomas
3    Daniel
4     Peter
5 Michael.2
6  Thomas.2
7     Ruben
8  Thomas.3
```

Does anybody have a suggestion how to achieve it in an automated way for a larger data frame?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have some options

```
my.data$names <- with(my.data, sub("\\.1$", "", paste(names, ave(seq_along(names),
        names, FUN=seq_along), sep=".")))
my.data$names
#[1] "Michael"   "Thomas"    "Daniel"    "Peter"     "Michael.2" "Thomas.2"  "Ruben"     "Thomas.3"
```

Or the `make.unique`

```
make.unique(as.character(my.data$names))
#[1] "Michael"   "Thomas"    "Daniel"    "Peter"     "Michael.1" "Thomas.1"  "Ruben"     "Thomas.2"
```

Comment: Wow, the second solution is pretty easy. Did not know that this function exist.

Comment: @burton030 Yes, it is easier, but the suffix will be starting from .1 instead of .2 in your expected

Comment: True, but for me this is also sufficient. Thank you.